# Hbase rest api multiple inserts

Tags: hbase, hbasestorage, hbase-client

We plan to use hbase rest api to perform inserts into a hbase table and would like to know if there is a way to insert multiple columns into a single column family or even multiple column families in a single call .

If not , as we plan to insert about 100+ columns for a particular record(row), this is causing us to make 100+ calls for a single row entry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert multiple columns for a single/multiple column family in a single PUT operation.  `--data` payload contains the `key` and `CellSet`, CellSet contains base64 encoded value of `cf:columnname` and `$` contains the base64 encoded value of column value.

For example :

```
  { "Row":[
      {
         "key":"d3d3LnNvbWVzaXRlLmNvbQ==",
         "Cell":[
            {
               "column":"QXV0aG9yczp0ZXN0MQ==",  // It can be cf1:name
               "$":"c29tZURhdGE="
            },
            {
               "column":"QXV0aG9yczp0ZXN0Mg==", // It can be cf2:address
               "$":"bW9yZURhdGE="
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

The final curl command will look like this:

```
curl -vi -X PUT \
         -H "Accept: text/json" \
         -H "Content-Type: text/json" \
         -d '{"Row":[{"key":"d3d3LnNvbWVzaXRlLmNvbQ==","Cell":[{"column":"QXV0aG9yczp0ZXN0MQ==","$":"c29tZURhdGE="},{"column":"QXV0aG9yczp0ZXN0Mg==","$":"bW9yZURhdGE="}]}]}' \
         "localhost:20550/table/rowkey"
```